# Prove the following equality: $1=\dfrac{4}{3}\cdot\dfrac{4}{5}\cdot\dfrac{6}{7}\cdot\dfrac{10}{9}\cdot\dfrac{12}{11}\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The product can be transformed into:

$1=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{5}\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{7}\right)\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{1}{9}\right)\cdots$

The result after a few products seems to approach $1$ as expected.
Here is my proof of the identity which uses trigonometry and the Weierstrass factorisation theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4777515/42969

However, I would like to know if the identity can be derived using an alternate method, without any reference to trigonometry. Additionally I would like to know if this identity has been observed before.

Comment: The product on the left is odd and the product on the right is even. If they are infinite then they both diverge.

Comment: The equality in the title is (debatably) true but for silly reasons (as John says both sides diverge) and it is not equivalent to the $1 = \dots $ identity. For that identity you first need to check that the infinite product converges at all (which can be done by taking the logarithm and then applying the alternating series test).

Comment: Ohh thanks for clarifying. I understand that this is a very silly question :) but the infinite product $(1+1/3)(1-1/5)\cdots$ does seem to approach $1$... Please try to prove this identity(and ignore my mistake of trying to equate diverging series) :$$1=(1+1/3)(1-1/5)\cdots$$ I have proved the identity using trigonometry but I would like a purely algebraic or non trigonometric approach :)

Comment: Maybe you could change the title and provide us your trigonometric proof?

Comment: You proved the identity  here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4777515/42969, which looks correct to me. Since it is an infinite product, any proof would involve some limiting process. Can you clarify what kind of “algebraic proof” you are looking for?

Comment: Yep, but I am obsessed with the Basel problem :) The way I proved it uses an extension of Weierstrass factorisation theorem. The Basel problem is a direct consequence of this theorem. I however want to prove the identity in the question with no reference to the factorisation, please use whatever method you like :) Proving this identity may help in an alternate derivation of the Basel problem

Comment: Are you familiar with https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf which gives 14 proofs of $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$?

Comment: So is the claimed equation $\prod_{k\ge0}\frac{(8k+4)^2(8k+6)(8k+10}{(8k+3)(8k+5)(8k+7)(8k+9)}=1$?

Comment: Yes indeed the product is $\prod_{k\ge0}\frac{(8k+4)^2(8k+6)(8k+10)\cdots}{(8k+3)(8k+5)(8k+7)(8k+9)\cdots}=1$(As per my limited understanding of these notations)

I'll expand the initial product:
$$1=(1+\dfrac{1}{3})(1-\dfrac{1}{5})(1-\dfrac{1}{7})(1+\dfrac{1}{9})(1+\dfrac{1}{11})(1-\dfrac{1}{13})(1-\dfrac{1}{15})(1+\dfrac{1}{17})(1+\dfrac{1}{19})\cdots$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I do know of pdf. However I want  to prove it in my own way. Since, by proving the identity in the question, it becomes easy to show that the square of the class number formula(L(1,-8)): $$\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=1+1/3-1/5-1/7+1/9+1/11-\cdots$$ is simply, $$\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}=1^2+(1/3)^2+(1/5)^2+(1/7)^2+(1/9)^2+\cdots$$

Comment: Follow-up question posted as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778744/proof-verification-of-basel-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the product:$(1+1)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{5}\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{7}\right)\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{1}{9}\right)\cdots$ , as:

$$\prod{\dfrac{(8n+2)(8n+4)(8n+4)(8n+6)}{(8n+1)(8n+3)(8n+5)(8n+7)}}--(1)$$

(Reference:New Wallis- and Catalan-Type Infinite Products, Jonathan Sondow, Huang Yi https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2712) (This is their proof, not mine)

Rewrite as:
$$\prod{\dfrac{(n+1/4)(n+1/2)(n+1/2)(n+3/4)}{(n+1/8)(n+3/8)(n+5/8)(n+7/8)}}--(2)$$

Euler's reflection formula:

$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\dfrac{x}{\sin(\pi x)}$

Weierstrass infinite product of gamma function gives us the general formula:

$\prod{\dfrac{(n+a_1)\cdots(n+a_k)}{(n+b_1)\cdots(n+b_k)}}=\dfrac{\Gamma(b_1)\cdots\Gamma(b_k)}{\Gamma(a_1)\cdots\Gamma(a_k)}$ (Where $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k=b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_k$)

Using these two formulae, $(2)$ becomes:

$$\dfrac{\Gamma(1/8)\Gamma(3/8)\Gamma(5/8)\Gamma(7/8)}{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(3/4)}=\dfrac{\sin(\pi/4)\sin(\pi/2)}{\sin(\pi/8)\sin(3\pi/8)}=2$$

Therefore, $$1=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{5}\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{7}\right)\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{1}{9}\right)\cdots$$ (End of referenced proof)

Consequently, since you're so obsessed with the Basel problem, you could substitute this result in the Dirichlet series $$L_{-8}(1)=\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=1+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\cdots$$

Squaring reveals, $$\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}=\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}+\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\dfrac{1}{9^2}+\cdots+2\left[\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{5}\right)\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{7}\right)\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{1}{9}\right)\cdots-1 \right]$$(The combining might have been a bit wonky tho)

which results in:
$$\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}=\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}+\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\dfrac{1}{9^2}+\cdots$$

Comment: I don't know too much about the mentioned Dirichlet class number formule derivation since it deals with advanced mathematics. However if the result $L_{-8}(1)$ can be derived without any reference to the Basel problem or the Zeta function, this could be an alternate approach to solving the Basel problem....